# Doing lots of boxplot using a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, boxplot

I have a file with another 30 files, imported by:

```
nomes<-list.files(pattern=".txt$")
dados<-list()

for (i in 1:length(nomes))
{
  dados[[i]]<-read.table(nomes[i])
}
```

I want to do a box plot with those files, but when I try this:

```
for (i in nomes)
{
boxplot(dados$i)
}
```

The i only recognize the last file. I do not understand what I am doing wrong.
Thank you for your help

Comment: if your list is not named I believe you should use boxplot(dados[[i]]) in your second loop. If you want the plots to display together you may need to uses something like `par(mfrow=c(2,2))`.

Comment: If you want not 30 graphs in one window but 30 windows, it is good idea to put `par(windows())` before `boxplot()`.

Comment: @cuttlefish44, Why `par(windows())` and not just `windows()`? It returns `NULL`, so `par(NULL)` does nothing.

Comment: @r2evans; You're right. But because the device `windows()` makes is initialized, in many case I use not just `windows()` but `par(windows(), par_arguments)`, so I said `par(windows())`.

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot. SOrrey for the dumb question, first loop.